# Transparency update via slider doesn't work in Firefox Mobile

Tags: firefox, mobile, three.js, slider, transparency

I've created a slider to change the transparency of a cube created with three.js. The code works well with all browsers in the desktop. However, in the Android System (version 5.0), the Firefox browser (version of May 8) is unable to update the transparency.

Here is the web page with the applet: http://www.im-uff.mat.br/tmp/how/simple-11.html

The code is here:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Orthogonal Projections 1</title>

    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->

    <script src="threejs.r91/build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs.r91/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <!-- ThreeJS Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load',
            function()
            {
                document.getElementById('tr').style.visibility = "visible";
            });


        var transparency_value = 0;

        function MakeQuadrilateral(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
        {
           var geo = new THREE.Geometry();

            // generate vertices
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x1,y1,z1));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x2,y2,z2));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x3,y3,z3));
            geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x4,y4,z4));


            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
            geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,2,3));


            // Return the geometry object
            return geo;
        }


       // Adds text to the screen
        function makeSpriteText(text)
        {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var size = 256; // CHANGED
            canvas.width = size;
            canvas.height = size;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; // CHANGED
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.font = '48px Times';
            context.fillText(text, size / 2, size / 2);

            var amap = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
            amap.needsUpdate = true;

            var mat = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
                map: amap,
                transparent: false,
                useScreenCoordinates: false,
                color: 0x0000ff // CHANGED
            });

            var sp = new THREE.Sprite(mat);
            return(sp);
        }


        // Check capabilities, and start if sufficient
        var hasWebGl = (function() {try {return !! window.WebGLRenderingContext &&
                !! document.createElement('canvas').getContext('experimental-webgl');}
        catch(e){return false;}})();
        var hasCanvas = !! window.CanvasRenderingContext2D; // Converts value to boolean
        var hasVibration = navigator.vibrate;


        window.onresize = function(event)
        {
            if (loaded == true)
            {
                loaded = false;

                context0.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(context0.camera, context0.renderer.domElement);
                context0.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
                context0.controls.noZoom = false;
                context0.controls.noPan = true;
                context0.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.2;
                context0.controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;
                context0.controls.staticMoving = false;
            }
        }

        if (hasCanvas)
        {
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
        } // End of if()

        function init()
        {
            // Setup idiom
            document.getElementById("msgwebglcontext0").innerHTML = "<br>";

            /* spawns the objects, scenes, cameras, renderers etc. */
            context0 = {color: 0xccff33, name: "0", width: 440, height: 440, factor: 30, arrowLength: 25};

            // set the scene
            if (hasWebGl)
            {
                context0.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true });
            }
            else
            {
                context0.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true });
            }
            context0.renderer.setSize(context0.width, context0.height);

            // Add the renderer to the document.
            // This should be called before THREE.TrackballControls().
            document.getElementById("webglcontext0").appendChild(context0.renderer.domElement);

            context0.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            context0.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, context0.height/context0.width, 2, 10000);   // 20: small values cause z-buffer fighting
            context0.camera.position.z = 70;
            context0.camera.position.x = 70;
            context0.camera.position.y = 70;
            context0.scene.add(context0.camera);
            context0.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(context0.camera, context0.renderer.domElement);
            context0.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
            context0.controls.noZoom = false;
            context0.controls.noPan = true;

            // Model
            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                }
            };
            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };
            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'platonic-cube.obj.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'obj/' );
                objLoader.load( 'platonic-cube.obj', function ( object )
                            {

                                        object.traverse(function (child)
                                        {
                                            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
                                            {
                                                // Polyhedra
                                                child.name = "pdp-faces";
                                                context0.scene.add(child);
                                                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );
                                                console.log('From loaded OBJ: ' + geometry.vertices.length);

                                                if ( Array.isArray( child.material ) )
                                                {
                                                    var n = child.material.length;
                                                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                                                    {
                                                       child.material[i].transparent = true;
                                                       child.material[i].opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                                                    };
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                       child.material.transparent = true;
                                                       child.material.opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                                                }

                                                // Edges
                                                var edges = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(child.geometry), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                edges.name = "pdp-edges";
                                                context0.scene.add(edges);

                                                // Vertices
                                                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                console.log('Geometry vertices length: ' + geometry.vertices.length);
                                                var vertices = [];
                                                var isNew;
                                                var tolerance = 0.0000001;
                                                if (geometry.vertices.length > 0)
                                                {
                                                    vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[0].x, geometry.vertices[0].y, geometry.vertices[0].z));
                                                }
                                                for (i = 1; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    l = vertices.length;
                                                    isNew = true;
                                                    for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
                                                    {
                                                        var d = geometry.vertices[i].distanceTo(vertices[j]);
                                                        if (d < tolerance)
                                                        {
                                                            isNew = false;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    if (isNew == true)
                                                    {
                                                        vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(geometry.vertices[i].x, geometry.vertices[i].y, geometry.vertices[i].z));
                                                    }
                                                }

/*
                                                alert('Unique vertices: ' + vertices.length);

                                                for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    alert(vertices[i].x);
                                                }
*/
                                                // https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Polyhedra.html
                                                // https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Polyhedra.html

                                                // Fit screen
                                                child.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
                                                var fov = context0.camera.fov * ( Math.PI / 180 );
                                                var objectSize = child.geometry.boundingSphere.radius;
                                                var distance = 0.7*Math.abs( objectSize / Math.sin( fov / 2 ) );
                                                context0.camera.position.z = 2.5*distance;
                                                context0.camera.position.x = 2.5*distance;
                                                context0.camera.position.y = 2.5*distance;

                                                // PLANE PROJECTIONS
                                                var geometry_xy =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                var geometry_xz =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                var geometry_yz =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( edges.geometry );
                                                geometry_xy.dynamic = true;
                                                geometry_xz.dynamic = true;
                                                geometry_yz.dynamic = true;
                                                for (i = 0; i < geometry_xy.vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var xOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].x;
                                                    var yOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].y;
                                                    var zOld = geometry_xy.vertices[i].z;
                                                    geometry_xy.vertices[i].set(xOld, yOld, -distance/3);
                                                    geometry_xz.vertices[i].set(xOld, -distance/3, zOld);
                                                    geometry_yz.vertices[i].set(-distance/3, yOld, zOld);
                                                    // console.log(geometry_xy.vertices[i].x + ' ' + geometry_xy.vertices[i].y + ' ' + geometry_xy.vertices[i].z);
                                                }
                                                geometry_xy.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                                                geometry_xz.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                                                geometry_yz.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


                                                var edges_xy = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_xy, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                var edges_xz = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_xz, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                var edges_yz = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry_yz, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {color: 0x000000}) );
                                                edges_xy.name = "pdp-edges-xy";
                                                edges_xz.name = "pdp-edges-xz";
                                                edges_yz.name = "pdp-edges-yz";
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_xy);
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_xz);
                                                context0.scene.add(edges_yz);


                                                // VERTICES
                                                var vertexGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(child.geometry.boundingSphere.radius/35.0, 12, 6 );
                                                var vertexMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } );
                                                var vertexSingleMesh = new THREE.Mesh( vertexGeometry );
                                                var vertexAmalgam = new THREE.Geometry();
                                                for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)
                                                {
                                                    var vMesh = vertexSingleMesh.clone();
                                                    vMesh.position.set(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
                                                    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( vertexAmalgam, vMesh );
                                                }
                                                var vertexMesh = new THREE.Mesh( vertexAmalgam, vertexMaterial );
                                                vertexMesh.name = "pdp-vertices";
                                                context0.scene.add(vertexMesh);
                                                context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-vertices").visible = false;


                                                // PLANES
                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var xyGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral( d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    d,  d, -d,
                                                                                   -d,  d, -d,
                                                                                   -d, -d, -d);
                                                var xyPlane = new THREE.Mesh(xyGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                xyPlane.name = "xyPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(xyPlane);

                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var xzGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral(  d, -d,  d,
                                                                                     d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d, -d,  d);
                                                var xzPlane = new THREE.Mesh(xzGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                xzPlane.name = "xzPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(xzPlane);

                                                var d = distance/3;
                                                var yzGeometry = MakeQuadrilateral( -d, -d,  d,
                                                                                    -d, -d, -d,
                                                                                    -d,  d, -d,
                                                                                    -d,  d,  d);
                                                var yzPlane = new THREE.Mesh(yzGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x090909, side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true }));
                                                yzPlane.name = "yzPlane";
                                                context0.scene.add(yzPlane);


                                                // AXES
                                                var xVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d ),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                xVector.name = "xVector";
                                                xVector.line.visible = true;
                                                xVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add( xVector );
                                                var xLabel = makeSpriteText("y");
                                                xLabel.name = "xLabel";
                                                xLabel.position.set(d + 0.7*d, -d, -d);
                                                xLabel.scale.set( d, d, d );
                                                context0.scene.add(xLabel);

                                                var yVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                yVector.name = "yVector";
                                                yVector.line.visible = true;
                                                yVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add(yVector );
                                                var yLabel = makeSpriteText("z");
                                                yLabel.name = "yLabel";
                                                yLabel.position.set(-d, d + 0.6*d, -d);
                                                yLabel.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
                                                context0.scene.add(yLabel);

                                                var zVector = new THREE.ArrowHelper(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
                                                                new THREE.Vector3(-d, -d, -d),
                                                                2*d + 0.5*d, 0x0000ff, 0.2*d, 0.1*d);
                                                zVector.name = "zVector";
                                                zVector.line.visible = true;
                                                zVector.cone.visible = true;
                                                context0.scene.add(zVector );
                                                var zLabel = makeSpriteText("x");
                                                zLabel.name = "zLabel";
                                                zLabel.position.set(-d, -d, d + 0.7*d);
                                                zLabel.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
                                                context0.scene.add(zLabel);

                                            }

                                        });

                }, onProgress, onError );
            });



            // var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
            // context0.scene.add(ambLight);
            context0.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            context0.light.position = context0.camera.position;
            context0.scene.add(context0.light);



            // Run
            context0.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            render();
            animate();

            loaded = true;
        } // End of init()

        function animate()
        {
            /* One animation tick */
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            context0.controls.update();
            render();
        } // End of animate()

        function render()
        {
            /* renders our little scene */
            context0.renderer.render(context0.scene, context0.camera);
        } // End of render()


</script>

</head>
<body> <!--    <body onload='disableScroll();'>         -->
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="webglcontext0" style="width:410px; height:50px; display: table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"></span>
<div id="msgwebglcontext0" style="text-align:center; display: table; margin-left: -3px;">
<span style="width:743px; height:30px; display: table-cell; text-align:justify; padding:10px; vertical-align: middle; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
Por favor, espere o navegador carregar a página. Caso
    isto já tenha acontecido e o applet abaixo não executou, isto significa que seu navegador parece não suportar WebGL ou esta opção não está habilitada.
Em caso de dúvidas, entre em contato conosco pelo e-mail:
<a href="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;&#99;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#101;&#117;&#100;&#111;&#115;&#100;&#105;&#103;&#105;&#116;&#97;&#105;&#115;&#64;&#105;&#109;&#46;&#117;&#102;&#102;&#46;&#98;&#114;">&#99;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#101;&#117;&#100;&#111;&#115;&#100;&#105;&#103;&#105;&#116;&#97;&#105;&#115;&#64;&#105;&#109;&#46;&#117;&#102;&#102;&#46;&#98;&#114;</a>.
</span>
</div>
</td>
<td align="center">
    <input
            name="transparency_range"
            id="tr"
            type="range"
            min="0"                    // default 0
    max="100"                  // default 100
    step="1"                   // default 1
    value="0"                 // default min + (max-min)/2
    oninput="updateTransparency(this.value)" onchange="updateTransparency(this.value)" ondrag="updateTransparency(this.value)"
    style="visibility: hidden"
    >
    <br>
    <span id="texto">0</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateTransparency(val)
    {
        transparency_value = val;
        if ((loaded == true))
        {
            if ( Array.isArray( context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material ) )
            {
                var n = context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material.length;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material[i].transparent = true;
                    context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material[i].opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                    context0.renderer.render(context0.scene, context0.camera);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material.transparent = true;
                context0.scene.getObjectByName("pdp-faces").material.opacity = (1 - transparency_value/100.0);
                context0.renderer.render(context0.scene, context0.camera);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = val;
    }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any hint about what is happening here?

Thanks in advance, Humberto.

Comment: Have you tried running a simpler test on Firefox for Android? Just a simple `material.opacity = Math.sin(seconds);` in your render loop to see if it's Firefox's WebGL capabilities that are limited on that platform, or maybe it's the HTML slider that's malfunctioning? Are you getting any warnings on the console?